# macro in visual studio 2015: expected an expression

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

I have this code

```
// show_time.c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define _timer() ({((double)(clock()))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;})

int main() {

    int i, j;

    double timer = _timer();

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
            i*j;

    printf("%f", _timer() - timer);
    return 0;
}
```

with `gcc` work fine, I get the time. But in Visual Studio 2015, `_timer` is marked and I get the message `expected an expression`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it works with gcc (now I know after following the duplicate link), but it's really overcomplex. A simpler expression does the same and is obviously more portable.

So drop the curly braces and the semi-colon.

That will work:

```
#define _timer() ((double)(clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)
```

or create a real function

```
double _timer() { return ((double)(clock()))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; }
```

but not a mix of the 2 constructs

Comment: works with gcc because `({..})` is a gnu stament expression https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html ... now I know

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define TIMER (((double)clock()) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC)

int main() {
    int i, j;
    double timer = TIMER;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
            i*j;
        }
    }
    printf("%f", TIMER - timer);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
0.018000
```

Please note that I use UPPERCASE name for a macro. And by putting the semicolon `;` and braces `{}` in the macro, it cannot be used as part of an expression.